# How to compare id in XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

My goal is to get in output XML file surname and amount of the clients. I want to match id from `<ClientList>` and id from `<AmountList>` and if there are the same show the amount. My XSL file doesn't work correctly.

I have such an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myData>
<ClientList>
    <Client>
        <surname>Kowalski</surname>
        <id>12</id>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <surname>Nowak</surname>
        <id>13</id>
    </Client>
</ClientList>
<AmountList>
     <Client>
        <id>12<id>
        <amount>500</amount>
    </Client>
    <Client>
       <id>13<id>
       <amount>300</amount>
</Client>
</AmountList>
<myData>
```

This one XML I would like to get:

```
<ClientList>
<Client>
   <surname>Kowalski</surname>
   <amount>500</amount>
</Client>
<Client>
  <surname>Nowak</surname>
  <amount>300</amount>
</Client>
</ClientList>
```

My XSL file doesn't work properly:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ClientList>
<xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
<Client>
   <surname>
       <xsl:value-of select="surname" />
   </surname>
   <amount>
       <xsl:variable name="Var1" select="substring(id, 1, 2)" />
       <xsl:variable name="Var2" select="substring(id, 1, 2)" />
       <xsl:if test="Var1 = Var2">AmountList/Client/amount</xsl:if> 
   </amount>
</Client>
</xsl:for-each>
</ClientList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there are a couple of small problems with your input XML: the `<id>`  nodes in the `<AmountList>`s aren't properly closed, and you're missing the closing tag for the root node `<myData>`.

Having fixed that, here is my suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/myData">
    <ClientList>
        <xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
        <Client>
            <surname>
                <xsl:value-of select="surname" />
            </surname>
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="/myData/AmountList/Client[id=current()/id]/amount" />
            </amount>
        </Client>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ClientList>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xPath expression `/myData/AmountList/Client[id=current()/id]/amount` means this:

> Starting at the root, find the `/myData/AmoutList/Client` node *whose* `id` child node *is equal to* the `id` child node of the *current context node*, and then select this node's `amount` child node.

The `current()` function is key to be able to do lookups like this, where you're looking elsewhere in the input tree for some node based on a value relative to the node you're currently on.

In this case the *current context node* returned by `current()` is the `Client` node because that's what is selected by the `for-each`. I find that it is good practice to always be aware of which is your current context node is at any point in an XSL transform.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <xsl:template match="myData">
        <xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
            <xsl:if test="id=../following-sibling::AmountList/Client/id">
                <xsl:element name="ClientList">
                    <xsl:element name="Client">
                <xsl:element name="surname">
                    <xsl:value-of select="surname"/>
                </xsl:element>
                        <amount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../following-sibling::AmountList/Client[id=current()/id]/amount"/>
                        </amount>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```